# Way to use WPF Image without attaching image at runtime

Tags: wpf, vb.net, image

I know how to attach an image to a XAML `<Image>` via VB.net runtime code. How would I do this the normal old way. (Attach the image within the IDE without using any code)

Before WPF one would browse for the image (in the Visual Studio IDE) it would somehow place it in the project and it would work.

Now I do this same thing, I can see the image in my Visual Studio IDE but during runtime the image appears blank.

How would I use the VS IDE to correctly browse for the image so it will display at runtime? Perhaps im doing something wrong a bit of help or any guidance would be awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have a folder in your project which contains your image files, in that case something similar to `<Image Source="/WpfApplication1/component;ImagesFolder/ImageName.png" />` would do the trick.

If you're looking for a non-code way, when you click on  tag, you can browse for imported files from `Source` Property from `Properties panel`